# Multiple OR in SQL string Variable, VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, where-clause

I am using a bit a code to Adjust form length and an SQL variable to modify the names that show up in a Combobox. I want to make sure that the names in the Comboboxes above the one that is being worked on, do not show any names. 
So if Combo1 has 40 names then Combo2 will only have 39 and so on. 
My problem seems to be when I use multiple "OR" within the WHERE Clause of the SQL String. Can anyone advice?

```
Private Sub Worker3_Change()
Dim Worker4STR As String

'Shows Worker 4

Me.Worker4.RowSource = ""
Worker4STR = "SELECT T1Workers.NonUserID, T1Workers.[FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName FROM T1Workers WHERE T1Workers.NonUserID <>" & _
              Me.Worker1.Value & " OR " & Me.Worker2.Value & " Or " & Me.Worker3.Value
Me.Worker4.RowSource = Worker4STR

Me.Worker4.AllowValueListEdits = False
Me.Worker4.ColumnCount = 2
Me.Worker4.ColumnWidths = "0, "

Me.Worker4.Visible = True
Me.Activity4.Visible = True
Me.w4a1s.Visible = True
Me.w4a1d.Visible = True
Me.w4a1o.Visible = True
Me.w4a2s.Visible = True
Me.w4a2o.Visible = True
Me.w4a2d.Visible = True
Me.w4a3s.Visible = True
Me.w4a3o.Visible = True
Me.w4a3d.Visible = True
Me.w4a4s.Visible = True
Me.w4a4o.Visible = True
Me.w4a4d.Visible = True
Me.w4a5s.Visible = True
Me.w4a5o.Visible = True
Me.w4a5d.Visible = True
Me.InsideHeight = 1440 * 4.6

End Sub
```

Thank you in Advance.
-Matt

Comment: have you tried IN ... where userid in (....)

Comment: by using the IN or NOT IN clause I do not get a return into the next Combobox.

Comment: can you show us your updated script with NOT IN?

Comment: Me.Worker4.RowSource = ""
Worker4STR = "SELECT T1Workers.NonUserID, T1Workers.[FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName FROM T1Workers WHERE T1Workers.NonUserID NOT IN" & _
              Me.Worker1.Value & " , " & Me.Worker2.Value & " , " & Me.Worker3.Value
Me.Worker4.RowSource = Worker4STR

Comment: so obviously you are missing the "(" and ")"

Comment: Yes, yes you have it, I was missing the open and close Paren.'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clause:

```
X <> A OR B OR C
```

Is not valid SQL.  You can use `NOT IN` instead:

```
"WHERE T1Workers.NonUserID NOT IN (" & _
              Me.Worker1.Value & " , " & _
              Me.Worker2.Value & " , " & _ 
              Me.Worker3.Value & " ) "
```

Note that if the values are strings they at a minimum need to be enclosed in quotes.  A *much better* solution is to use SQL parameters instead, but I do not know if that's possible with whatever `Worker4` is.

Comment: By using the "IN" or "NOT IN" Clauses the code now returns nothing in the next ComboBox. Is there another method?

Comment: Thank you BOTH! I was missing the Parenthesis that has done the trick!